# database schema column naming convention, hour or hours?

Tags: sql

I have a table "jobs" and there is a column which stores data about hours of work, it's integer type.

I wonder it should be named "hour" or "hours"? Which one is better?

Answer (score 3):

The word hour may signify a fixed point in time, or one hour as duration (60 minutes).

The word hours may signify a duration of several hours.

I think hours is preferred here. But I would make the name more clear so that their is no confusion. As related to jobs hours might also signify the start or end hour.
Maybe WORKED_HOURS correctly names what the column holds?

Comment: Thanks for your immediate answer! I finally decide to use "worked_hours" (it better than "hours") instead of "hour" or "hours" in this case. =)